# Make a new frame with only mode-line

Tags: mode-line, osx

I want to create a new frame that contains nothing but the mode-line. Especially not a file buffer.

Why do I need this? I use [org-mode's clocking](http://orgmode.org/manual/Clocking-work-time.html) to time my work. Org-mode displays the timer for the current task I'm working on in the mode-line, and updates the timer in real-time. I use apps other than Emacs, so when I switch to them (e.g.. when using the browser or terminal) I still want to be able to look at the running timer. I thought I could create a new frame, but when I now click on the timer in the mode-line the .org file is getting opened in the new frame (which is already resized to show only mode-line) instead of jumping back to it in the first frame.

Here's how my mode-line looks (the blue bar) -- that is all I want on the new frame:

[image]

(Eventually I will have to figure out how to make the new frame appear always-on-top, but that is outside the scope of this question)

I use OS X if that is relevant.

Comment: Just a heads up, I'm working on some elisp and a macruby script that will display the org mode line information in the OSX menu bar. It's working for me but I'm going to try to wrap it up nicely.

Comment: @JordonBiondo - excellent! your solution may turn out to be even better than what I'm doing here. looking forward to it. please keep me updated.

Comment: You should retitle and rephrase your question, if you really feel that the answers you are saying "**Excellent!**" to respond to it. Because as far as I can tell they do *not* answer your request for a frame with "**nothing but a mode line**" - at all (and I doubt that any answer will). IOW, if you've relaxed your aim since the original formulation of your request, please consider updating the question accordingly.

Comment: I agree, after reading, it really seemed like OP had a specific problem, but was asking for only one solution, not the best solution.

Comment: @Drew - Do you suggest any specific edits? PythonNut's original solution answers my original request. Note that I said "Especially not a file buffer.", and his solution - although creates an empty buffer - doesn't lead to file buffers appearing on the new frame.

Comment: The title and question say that you want a **frame with only a mode line**. The solutions given produce an ordinary frame, albeit with an empty buffer and no menu-bar or tool-bar. They do not produce a frame that has only a mode line (for which I think the answer is probably: that's impossible - but I'm not certain).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extending [*Jorgen Schäfer's* answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7701/2642) with 
[*Matthew Piziak's*](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/594/matthew-piziak) suggestion produces the following snippet:

```el
(with-current-buffer (generate-new-buffer "*empty*")
  (make-frame '((minibuffer . nil)
                 (unsplittable . t)
                 (buffer-predicate . (lambda (x) nil))
                 (height . 2)
                 (left-fringe . 0)
                 (right-fringe . 0)
                 (tool-bar-lines . 0)
                 (menu-bar-lines . 0)))
  (set-window-dedicated-p
    (get-buffer-window (current-buffer) t) t))
```

As far as I can tell, this correctly locks the window to an empty buffer. Attempting to switch to a different buffer will open the buffer in an existing window in the parent frame.

Comment: Excellent, I've verified this to work. Any way to make the new frame inherit the font-size (and font-name) of the main frame? Also, can the redundant buffer-specific parts of the mode line -- `*empty*  All L1 (Fundamental)` -- be removed? Here's how mine looks: http://i.imgur.com/iOLw57c.png

Comment: @SridharRatnakumar Fortunately, stripping the extra mode-line info is trivial. I've amended my answer to include that. I'm not quite sure what you mean by preserving the font? Isn't the buffer empty?

Comment: I was referring to the font property of the text in the mode-line (not the empty buffer).

Comment: ah, your later code cleared the mode-line of the main frame as well! If this is not possible, let's revert that change and I'll accept your answer (it satisfies the question).

Comment: I just noticed that too. I've fixed it. The mode-line font doesn't change when I do it, so I'm not sure what's up.

Comment: best to revert to your original solution. with the new code, the modeline is completely empty even after clocking in org.

Comment: @SridharRatnakumar alright, here you go.

Answer (score 5):

This is the best I could come up with:

```
(with-current-buffer (generate-new-buffer "*empty*")
  (make-frame '((minibuffer . nil)
                (unsplittable . t)
                (buffer-predicate . (lambda (x) nil))
                (height . 2)
                (left-fringe . 0)
                (right-fringe . 0)
                (tool-bar-lines . 0)
                (menu-bar-lines . 0))))
```

I do not see a way to disable at least one window with one buffer there, but the one displayed using this snippet is not associated with any file. The `buffer-predicate` there prevents the frame from being chosen to display any (other) buffers, so if you can deal with one extra empty line, this should do it.

Comment: It doesn't work as expected. Buffers are still being activated in the new frame. Here's an animated gif to illustrate: http://i.imgur.com/07Q3tcW.gifv

Comment: Using [`display-buffer-alist`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Choosing-Window.html) might be the solution to this.

Comment: I do not know why org's use here does not adhere to the `buffer-predicate`. Using `display-buffer-alist` might be an idea indeed, but I do not know how to use it to prevent a specific frame from being used.

Comment: Why is org to blame here? The new frame also displays buffers switched using `C-x b`. To me, the above code behaves exactly the same as `M-x new-frame` and manually resizing it.

Comment: Could this be fixed with `set-window-dedicated-p`?

Comment: @MatthewPiziak yes. I have a working code example. Should I post it, or send it to you?

Comment: @PythonNut - perhaps you can post it as an answer here.

Comment: The `buffer-predicate` is, according to info, only used by the `other-buffer` function, i.e. it does not prevent other functions from displaying any buffer in the frame.

Answer (score 3):

### Solution for displaying the org-clock information in the OSX menu bar

Here is an alternative solution to the problem you specified:

> I use apps other than Emacs, so when I switch to them (e.g.. when
>   using the browser or terminal) I still want to be able to look at the
>   running timer.

You can use this to display the information from org-clock in the osx menubar which you should almost always be able to see.

https://github.com/jordonbiondo/osx-org-clock-menubar Available on MELPA

Note that this requires macruby.

What it looks like while clocked in.

[image]

Comment: A simple implementation that does not rely on macruby can be done with `emacsclient -e "(org-clock-get-clocked-time)"` and bitbar: https://getbitbar.com/

Comment: That's awesome you should write up a solution!

Comment: There is a good solution here: https://xiangji.me/2020/12/27/displaying-orgmode-clock-in-menu-bar/

Answer (score 3):

## Yet another solution for org-clock in osx

A small box in status bar. It turns red when you didn't clock in.

[image: illustration for red box, see github page]

https://github.com/koddo/org-clock-statusbar-app

Comment: I'm a bit late and do not answer the exact question, but I offer an alternative that would work for someone.