# How to prevent window split in a single frame

Tags: frames

I'm in emacs 24.something on a Windows platform.
I have an agenda generated by org that I would like to keep on continuous display.
I use multiple frames, and multiple windows per frame, for my other work.
What I would like is a single frame with a dedicated window displaying my agenda buffer that is NOT split

```el
(set-window-dedicated (selected-window) t)
```

seems to help, but doesn't quite do the trick.

Any ideas?

Comment: The following link contains a detailed example of how to display a particular buffer in a particular frame, which includes making it the only window in the frame -- it also includes solutions for non-file-visiting buffers (like `*Org Agenda*`) and file-visiting buffers:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18371427/2112489  Unfortunately, it is a little complex and may take some time to digest and incorporate into your workflow.  I'm sorry that I don't have a simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

A similar question was asked [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7697/make-a-new-frame-with-only-mode-line). Try this solution:

```el
(with-current-buffer
  ;; initialize org-agenda here
  ;; this sexp MUST return a buffer,
  ;; to be used by with-current-buffer
  (blah blah initialize org-agenda blah blah)
  (make-frame '((unsplittable . t)))
  (set-window-dedicated-p
    (get-buffer-window (current-buffer) t) t))
```

*Disclaimer*:
I, personally, don't use `org-agenda`, so I can't guarantee that this will work. It should if `org-agenda` behaves nicely.

Comment: You should warn the reader that the first argument of with-current-buffer has to be the agenda buffer.

Comment: Indeed. Edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

There was only one thing wrong with the code you tried, in terms of making the window dedicated:

> (set-window-dedicated (selected-window) t)

The function is **`set-window-dedicated-p`**, not `set-window-dedicated`.  Try again, without the typo:

```el
 (set-window-dedicated-p (selected-window) t)
```

That will prevent both you and Emacs from using the window for another buffer. For example, `C-x b` will raise an error.

To prevent automatic splitting of the window, you can do this:

```el
 (set-frame-parameter nil 'unsplittable t)
```

That will *not* prevent you from splitting the window, e.g. using `C-x 2`, but it will prevent Emacs from splitting it automatically.