# Single mode line for all windows

Tags: buffers, window, frames, mode-line

Is it possible to have only one mode line (sometimes referred as "statusbar") for all windows?

I'd like to make this single mode line show information about the currently selected buffer.

Comment: Perhaps you could borrow the concept in the attached thread and create a dedicated window on the bottom of every frame, which shows only a custom mode-line?  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7697/make-a-new-frame-with-only-mode-line

Comment: Surely you mean windows, not frames?

Comment: Good catch. Yes, I mean windows.

Answer (score 8):

I don't have a solution for a single modeline, but here are two possible alternative solutions:

### 1. Only render the mode line in the active window:

If you use powerline, you could wrap your mode-line-format in:

`((:eval (when (powerline-selected-window-active) ...)))`

then change the `mode-line-inactive` face so blends with your background but still separates buffers with:

```
(set-face-attribute 'mode-line-inactive nil
                    :underline t
                    :background (face-background 'default))
```

This will look like this:

[image]

### 2. Use the `frame-title-format`

Your `frame-title-format` determines what is show on the top of your frame when running in a gui.

Set the `frame-title-format' like you would your`mode-line-format` and them set your mode-line-format to something blank-ish.

Answer (score 6):

I've finally achieved this by hacking emacs. [image: Demo]

You can get the source code from https://github.com/amosbird/emacs/tree/onemodeline . Basically it uses mini-window's header line to render current buffer's modeline.

Comment: Does this still work/work with emacs 26.1?

Comment: @rien333 It should. But this method is indeed very fragile. There are still hardcoded logic that requires mini window being one line. However I couldn't find them all.

Comment: There is also [common-header-mode-line](https://github.com/Bad-ptr/common-header-mode-line.el), though I haven't managed to configure it yet.